# PMD static code analysis for code snippets

Tags: java, pmd

Is it possible to analyse half-completed code snippets with PMD? for example, a code sample like this.

```
Random r = new Random();
int i = r.nextInt(5);

switch(i) {
    case 0:
        // do something
        break;
    case 1:
        // do something else
        break;
    case 2:
        // do something else
        break;
    case 3:
        // do something else
        break;
    case 4:
        // do something else
        break;
}
```

Comment: PMD can't parse snippets. The smallest thing PMD can analyze is a compilation unit (a proper java file with one class), otherwise it can't parse it. If you however put that snippet in a Test.java file within a `public class Test { public void foo() { … } }`, that should be enough for PMD